# MySQL - UPDATE query with SET statement dependent on the outcome of the previous SET statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Here is a tabular representation of what I would like to achieve with an UPDATE statement.

```
+----+----+---+---+----+----------+---------------+---------------+
| ID | A  | B | C | D  |  Calc A  |    Calc B     |    Calc C     |
+----+----+---+---+----+----------+---------------+---------------+
|  1 |  6 | 5 | 2 | 10 | =[A]-[B] | =[Calc A]/[D] | =[B]/[Calc B] |
|  2 |  8 | 5 | 2 | 10 | =[A]-[B] | =[Calc A]/[D] | =[B]/[Calc B] |
|  3 | 10 | 5 | 2 | 10 | =[A]-[B] | =[Calc A]/[D] | =[B]/[Calc B] |
+----+----+---+---+----+----------+---------------+---------------+
```

My Current UPDATE statement to achieve this is as follows...

```
UPDATE [EXAMPLE]
SET [Calc A]    = A - B
    , [Calc B]  = [Calc A] / D
    , [Calc C]  = B / [Calc B]
```

However it is not working as intended. [Calc A] will calculate correctly on the first UPDATE. However [Calc B] will calculate using the OLD value in [Calc A] and not the NEW updated value I just wrote to the database. This holds true for [Calc C] which again refers to the OLD value of [Calc B].

If you perform the UPDATE statement 3 times the data will calculate out correctly. [Calc A] is set correctly in the first calculation, then [Calc B] will reference the correct updated value of [Calc A] in the second UPDATE, then [Calc C] will reference the correct value of [Calc B] in the 3rd UPDATE.

So my question is how do I set all the columns to their correct value in ONE update statement?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server? Your use of square brackets makes me think you're using Microsoft.

Comment: @BillKarwin MySQL, only used the square brackets because of spaces in the field names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do the calculations independently:

```
update [EXAMPLE]
set [Calc A] = A - B,
    [Calc B] = (A - B) / D,
    [Calc C] = B / ((A - B) / D)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes this works. However, in a lot of cases like this each individual calculation can be very complicated and long and simply doing the calculations independently results in some VERY VERY VERY long calculation statements. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I suggest that you use a trigger. do the calculation once and reuse  for other columns,

Comment: I've never done that before. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution to this problem using local variables in the SET statements. See below.

```
UPDATE [EXAMPLE]
SET [Calc A]    = @calc_a : = A - B
    , [Calc B]  = @calc_b := @calc_a / D
    , [Calc C]  = B / @calc_b
```

Comment: This is not guanteed to work, as it is not sure in which column order will the set operation be called. MySQL has documented this very clearly.

Comment: @GurV Can you elaborate? I am not sure exactly what you mean by this? Are you saying that the SET statements will not necessarily occur sequentially? i.e. the operation could occur as CalcC, CalcA then CalcB as opposed to CalcA, CalcB then CalcC?